# Get value or text of textfield or select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of input fields' ids. The problem is that they are either text field or select box. For select box, I want the inner text and for the input field I would like to get the value and put it in an object. It's identical to `serializeObject()` if not for the treatment of select box. I wonder if the following snippet is best way to achieve this goal:

```
var ids = [/* a bunch of ids here */]

var inputs = {}

$.each(ids, function(k,v){
    // is there any jQuery ready-made way to do this?
    var input = $('#' + v + ' :selected').text(); 
    inputs[v] = (input === '') ? $('#' + v).val() : input;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.each(ids, function(k,v){
  inputs[v] = ($('#' + v).is('select')) ?
    $('#' + v).find("option:selected").text() :
    $('#' + v).val();
}
```

That should do it. o/

Comment: I think this is readable enough. But this is slightly incorrect because we need to append # to the id selector like this `$('#' + v)`. Putting that into this code does hurt the eyes :)

Comment: True, my bad. Should be ok now. :)

Comment: @aazev I changed your code to make it more readable. Do you accept it as is? I just changed newlines/indentation.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I think the code looks pretty and it avoids the ugly string comparison. I still think we're reinventing the wheel a bit too much though. I'll hold out for some other options.

Comment: A concern I have is that, although hypothetical and out of the question's scope in its current forms, if I have to separate more than 2 types of input, this approach will get messy...